# Slicing my data frame is returning unexpected results

Tags: python, pandas, slice, nan

I have 13 CSV files that contain billing information in an unusual format. Multiple readings are recorded every 30 minutes of the day. Five days are recorded beside each other (columns). Then the next five days are recorded under it. To make things more complicated, the day of the week, date, and billing day is shown over the first recording of KVAR each day.

The image blow shows a small example. However, imagine that KW, KVAR, and KVA repeat 3 more times before continuing some 50 rows later.

[image: For Example]

My goal as to create a simple python script that would make the data into a data frame with the columns: DATE,  TIME,   KW, KVAR,   KVA, and    DAY.

The problem is my script returns NaN data for the KW, KVAR, and KVA data after the first five days (which is correlated with a new instance of a for loop). What is weird to me is that when I try to print out the same ranges I get the data that I expect.

My code is below. I have included comments to help further explain things. I also have an example of sample output of my function.

```
def make_df(df):

    #starting values
    output = pd.DataFrame(columns=["DATE", "TIME", "KW", "KVAR", "KVA", "DAY"])
    time = df1.loc[3:50,0]
    val_start = 3
    val_end = 51
    date_val = [0,2]
    day_type = [1,2]

    # There are 7 row movements that need to take place. 
    for row_move in range(1,8):
        day = [1,2,3]
        date_val[1] = 2
        day_type[1] = 2

        # There are 5 column movements that take place.

        # The basic idea is that I would cycle through the five days, grab their data in a temporary dataframe,
        # and then append that dataframe onto the output dataframe
        for col_move in range(1,6):
            temp_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["DATE", "TIME", "KW", "KVAR", "KVA", "DAY"])
            temp_df['TIME'] = time

            #These are the 3 values that stop working after the first column change
            # I get the values that I expect for the first 5 days
            temp_df['KW'] = df.iloc[val_start:val_end, day[0]]
            temp_df['KVAR'] = df.iloc[val_start:val_end, day[1]]
            temp_df['KVA'] = df.iloc[val_start:val_end, day[2]]

            # These 2 values work perfectly for the entire data set
            temp_df['DAY'] = df.iloc[day_type[0], day_type[1]]
            temp_df["DATE"] = df.iloc[date_val[0], date_val[1]]

            # trouble shooting
            print(df.iloc[val_start:val_end, day[0]])
            print(temp_df)

            output = output.append(temp_df)

            # increase values for each iteration of row loop.
            # seems to work perfectly when I print the data
            day = [x + 3 for x in day]
            date_val[1] = date_val[1] + 3
            day_type[1] = day_type[1] + 3

        # increase values for each iteration of column loop
        # seems to work perfectly when I print the data
        date_val[0] = date_val[0] + 55
        day_type [0]= day_type[0] + 55

        val_start = val_start + 55
        val_end = val_end + 55

    return output

test = make_df(df1)
```

Below is some sample output. It shows where the data starts to break down after the fifth day (or first instance of the column shift in the for loop). What am I doing wrong?

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

Could be `pd.append` requiring matched row indices for numerical values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
output = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,2), columns=['a','b'])  # fake data 
output['c'] = list('abcdefghij')  # add a column of non-numerical entries

tmp = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c'])
tmp['a'] = output.iloc[0:2, 2] 
tmp['b'] = output.iloc[3:5, 2]  # generates NaN
tmp['c'] = output.iloc[0:2, 2] 
data.append(tmp)
```

---

(initial response)

How does `df1` look like? Is `df.iloc[val_start:val_end, day[0]]` have any issue past the fifth day? The codes didn't show how you read from the csv files, or `df1` itself.

My guess: if `val_start:val_end` gives invalid indices on the sixth day, or `df1` happens to be malformed past the fifth day, `df.iloc[val_start:val_end, day[0]]` will return an empty Series object and possibly make its way into `temp_df`. `iloc` do not report invalid row indices, though similar column indices would trigger IndexError.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,3), columns=['a','b','c'], index=np.arange(5))  # fake data
df.iloc[0:2, 1]  # returns the subset
df.iloc[100:102, 1]  # returns: Series([], Name: b, dtype: float64)
```

A little off topic but I would recommend preprocessing the csv files rather than deal with indexing in Pandas DataFrame, as the original format was kinda complex. Slice the data by date and later use `pd.melt` or `pd.groupby` to shape them into the format you like. Or alternatively try multi-index if stick with Pandas I/O.

Comment: Thanks for the response Nriuam. `df.iloc[val_start:val_end, day[0]]` for any value of the `df1` data frame returns the results that I would expect. That is why I am confused. I can iterate through the entire data frame and print out the results, but when I assign the values to `temp_df` I get  NaN.

I will check out melt and groupby after some proprocessing.

Comment: @thomaskh522 Looks like `pd.append` relies on index, just like `pd.concat`. For `TIME` you used `df1.loc[3:50,0]`, then Pandas expected the same row indices for all other values assigned, which rendered numerical values to `NaN` (strings not affected). Updating related tests to my answer in a minute. Can you try match the indices for all columns?

Comment: @thomaskh522 Sorry strings could be affected as well (rendered NaN), but I still suspect NaNs to be the result of row indices impair.